# Android "Search" Activity and corresponding XML

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

Below is an `Android Activity` and corresponding `XML layout`. The function of the class is to search an `SQLite database` to show results to the user.

Can I get a review of the code quality? This is my first Android app so feedback would be greatly appreciated as I do not know standard Android/Java practices to aim for.

**Activity Code:**

```java
package com.example.briapp;

import java.util.List;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Activity that contains functionality for searching by average attention value
 * 
 * @author Ross
 * 
 */
public class AttentionAverageSearch extends ActionBarActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    // declare variables
    TextView instruction;
    EditText avgEntered;
    TextView tvResults;
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    String log;
    Button sub;
    List<Session> results;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.attentionaveragesearch);

        initialiseVars();
    }

    /**
     * Method that initialises variables for the activty and sets onclick
     * listener for button
     */
    public void initialiseVars() {

        instruction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAverageAttSearch1);
        avgEntered = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnterSpecificAttAvgVal);
        tvResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAvgAttSearchResults1);
        tvResults.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAvgAttSearch);
        sub.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    /**
     * On click listener for button(s)
     */
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnAvgAttSearch:

            // validation to ensure a blank entry isn't given
            if (avgEntered.getText().toString().length() < 1) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter something !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else {

                // if valid
                final String entry = avgEntered.getText().toString();
                int avgValToSearch = Integer.parseInt(entry);

                // /setting results equal to return value of search
                results = db.getSpecificAverageAtt(avgValToSearch);

                // hides keyboard when btn pressed
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus()
                        .getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

                tvResults.setText(listToString(results));

            }

            break;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method used to format the output of a List
     * 
     * @param list
     * @return String
     */
    public static String listToString(List<?> list) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            result += "" + list.get(i) + "\n\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

**Corresponding XML:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menubackground"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAverageAttSearch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:text="Enter Minimum Average value..."
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEnterSpecificAttAvgVal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter value..."
        android:inputType="number" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAvgAttSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle2"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="10"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAvgAttSearchResults1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:maxLines="30"
        android:minLines="5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text=" Results..."
        android:textSize="17dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, Since you have added the sqlite tag you might want to include "DatabaseHelper" as well.

Comment: The database helper class is very large (over 1000 lines), that's why it isn't included? I didn't want to ask for a review of a class that large!

Comment: youre feedback on my code quality would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You know there is a code smell if a class is 1000+ lines

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Initializing should be done automatically from your constructor. Right now you're exposing it as a public method that may or may not get called: this will guaranteed cause problems when someone forgets to initialize. Considering it doesn't add value in the first place I would just call it automatically in your constructor.

---

Use comments to convey *why* you're doing something, not *what*. I can tell from the code that you do `someVariable + 1` so I don't need a comment for that. What I do need is a comment to tell me `//Add offset to make up for <insert-crazy-edgecase>`.

Applying this to your code I would say that comments like this are not needed:

```
/**
 * Method that initialises variables for the activty and sets onclick
 * listener for button
 */
```

because a well-named method will already give me that information: when I read

```
public void initializeFields()
```

I already know everything that the comment told me. Likewise,

```
/**
 * On click listener for button(s)
 */
```

will not give me any more information than

```
public void onClick(View v)
```

already tells me. Yes, you specify that it's about buttons but that's very minor.

This, however, is a good comment because it is less obvious from the code:

```
// hides keyboard when btn pressed
```

---

You have too much whitespace in your .java file for my taste; don't leave these empty lines after `switch`/`case`/`if`/methods/etc. It just makes it harder to digest because the information is spread out too much.

---

I'm not a fan of intermediate variables that have a short declaration and are only used once. I'd change

```
final String entry = avgEntered.getText().toString();
int avgValToSearch = Integer.parseInt(entry);
```

to

```
int avgValToSearch = Integer.parseInt(avgEntered.getText().toString());
```

---

No abbreviations[1]. Change that to `averageValueToSearch` and `initializeVariables`.

[1]: *almost* none. Some very specific ones like `db` I can live with.

---

`listToString()` is a helper method. If it is *only* used in `AttentionAverageSearch` then it should be declared there and made `private`.

If it is used elsewhere as well, then it should be either moved up into the hierarchy (if that makes sense in your structure) or to a separate helper class.

---

Use a `StringBuilder` when concatenating strings in a loop.

---

I don't like using `sub.setOnClickListener(this);` and then implementing `View.OnClickListener` on activity level. You end up, as you do, with one big click handler while you might as well just create a method dedicated to that button. It will be clearer and easier to find as well (when you have 20 buttons, you would have them all laid out in your IDE's class view window).

---

Restrict visibility unless you actually want an outside class to access it. Both `initializeVars` and `click` are *not* things the outside world should access so make them `private`.

Comment: Thank you that is great feedback! Could you possibly give me a bit more detail/example on the commenting?

Comment: @user3968848: I elaborated on it, does that answer any doubts left?

Comment: It does surely,generally would you say that the code is of a decent standard? thanks

Comment: Also, should I initialise all my vars in the constructor?

Comment: Note: I have a javadoc comment on every method as I was told, in college, it was good practice? Perhaps this is not true

Comment: The code is generally fine but it's a little too few to accurately gauge the quality. Don't hesitate to submit that 1K LOC databasehelper for a review, we've dealt with bigger ones and it sounds like that might be an interesting one for a review. I typically initialize them in the constructor, yes. Unless you have a very specific usecase where you actually need them in a separate method, you should just stuff it in the constructor (although it might make it clearer when there are other kinds of initializing going on in the constructor).

Comment: Public methods typically get javadoc, yes. Non-public ones do too sometimes, but not always since that is not part of the public API. They often just stick to a casual comment (`//`). Note that I added a little remark at the end: you should restrict the visibility more.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will post the databasehelper class soon!